# TYPE IS TABLE OF, from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm currently migrating some procedures from Oracle to Postgres, those procedures are using a type that was created to handle an unknown number of values:

```
TYPE array_text IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (50);
```

So they can declare a variable like:

```
myValues in array_text;
```

And use it later this way:

```
myValues(1) := 'VALUE1';
myValues(2) := 'VALUE2';
...
```

So I have been learning and trying to replicate this behavior using Postgres, but until now I can't find a properly way. I tried creating a composite type like:

```
CREATE TYPE array_text AS (
    val varchar(50)
);
```

Or

```
CREATE TYPE array_text AS (
    v varchar(50)[]
);
```

However I can't use them the same way as the original is used, and actually I couldn't create a successful test.

How could I get this behavior or something similar? So I can set and get values and even count its length like in Oracle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much simpler in Postgres than in Oracle - you don't need to define a collection type. Just declare an array.

The sensible and most efficient replacement of `TYPE array_text IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (50);` is `text[]` in Postgres.

To get the length of the array use `cardinality()`. You don't need a special method to extend its capacity, just assign a value to the index you want. The only major difference is, that there is no (easy) way to *shrink* an array in Postgres.

```
declare
   myValues text[];
   num_values int;
begin

  myValues[1] := 'VALUE1';
  myValues[2] := 'VALUE2';

  num_values := cardinality(myvalues); // yields 2

  myValues[3] := 'VALUE3';
  num_values := cardinality(myvalues); // yields 3
end;
```

---

To extend the answer: you can also use table types like that. So you don't need to define an intermediate "table of" collection type, just to use a table's type for an array.

```
create table person
(
  id integer,
  firstname text,
  lastname text
);
```

Then you can use

```
do
$$
declare
  people_list person[];
begin
  people_list[1] := row(42, 'Arthur', 'Dent')::person;
  raise notice 'Name %', people_list[1].firstname;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Oracle also has the [`CARDINALITY()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions015.htm#SQLRF06305) - its just that you can also use `myValues.COUNT` and it appears to be the better known Oracle solution.

Answer (score 3):

postgres doesn't allow tables (or composite types) with unnamed columns

unlike tables arrays can be multidimensional, and also can start other than at [1] or [0], so you may need to check that the input is of the correct form (unless incorrect input 
implicitly causes an error)

```
CREATE TYPE array_text AS (
    val varchar(50)[]
);
```

but this creates a composite type with one attribute which is an array... so you need to used `.val` to access the array.

```
jasen=# do $$ 
declare a array_text;
begin 
   a.val[0]='won';
   a.val[1]='too';
   raise notice 'len=%',array_length(a.val,1); end;
$$;
NOTICE:  len=2
DO
```

but if you declare the array in-line you can just use a simple name.

```
jasen=# do $$ 
declare a varchar(50)[];
begin 
   a[5]='eigh';
   a[6]='bee';
   raise notice 'len=%',array_length(a,1); end;
$$;
NOTICE:  len=2
DO
```

Comment: With your example I could finally run my test, this time I'm going to choose the simply array way to maybe avoid complexity when calling them from Java.